# Make a page wait for 15 minutes

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to make a page wait for 15 minutes but neither Thread.sleep or Web driver wait seems to be working.Can anyone suggest a solution for my problem?

Comment: Your code trials and relevant HTML please.

Comment: Please share the code snippet what you have tried so far

Comment: Sounds like it's time for "Timer to the rescue"

Comment: There are a lot of downvotes and closure request. I think OP needed some help. So I have tried to extend all the help related to **Thread.sleep()** and **WebDriverWait**. Please reconsider your downvotes and closure request.

Comment: @Nagashri what do you mean by 'make a page wait'? If u r looking to make a page functionality wait or stop, selenium test programs not going to help u. U got to mess with the webapp code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to make a `Web Page` wait for 15 minutes, **`Thread.sleep();`** or **`WebDriverWait`** are not the intended ways. To make the `Web Page` wait you have to inject **`Javascript`** within the **`Web Browser`**

As you tried **`Thread.sleep()`** and **`WebDriverWait`**, here are a few details :

- [**`Thread.sleep()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html) : Is a **`Java`** based method from **`Thread Class`** which holds any further execution of a thread for the specified amount of time.
- [**`WebDriverWait`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) : Is a **`Selenium`** based **`Class`**  which extends **`org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait<WebDriver>`** and is a specialization of **`FluentWait`** that uses **`WebDriver`** instances and is invoked over `WebElements` to attain a certain characteristics over a period of timespan.

From your question, I am not sure about the problem you are facing with **`Thread.sleep();`** or **`WebDriverWait`** but **`Thread.sleep();`** seems works fine for **`15 minutes`** as follows :

### Sample Program :

```
package demo;

public class SLEEP 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
    {    
        System.out.println("Program Started");
        Thread.sleep(1000*60*1);
        System.out.println("Program Ended");
    }
 }
```

### Console Output :

```
Program Started
Program Ended
```

> **Note** : However while working with **`Selenium`**, **`Thread.sleep();`** should be avoided as it degrades the **`Test Performance`**. Instead we must use **`ExpectedConditions`** with a proper method from this [**`list`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html).