# Selenium IDE element not found select an option from dropdownlist

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm new to selenium

My script is to:

1. open one website
2. click one button and then open go to another website
3. a drop down list will be shown in the new website, i need to select one option from the list

   [image]

But I failed.

The log said:

> Element id=primaryroles not found

I tried to change the target to detailed HTML element, like
`//html/frameset/frame/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr/td/div[@id='clientBackground']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/label/select`

But it failed as well.

I think the problem may be that new website did not load fully, so i add command "waitforpagetoload" value30000  but the error is time run out

I run out of my brain, please help me :)
The weirdest thing is that **i could execute this single command successfully**, but i play this current test suit/case, it will fail when it come to this command.

Comment: Please edit the post so the image would be inside the question body as image, not as link

Comment: Open your page in Chrome, hit F12, go to the Console tab. Here, try some dynamic xpaths like: $x("//*[@id='primaryRoles'") - Let me know if this command works

Comment: Show your script please.

Comment: <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">demo5</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
 <td>open</td>
 <td>/medtronic/</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>//a[@onclick='javascript:launchadmin();']</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>selectAndWait</td>
 <td>id=primaryRoles</td>
 <td>label=People Administration</td>
</tr>

Comment: Need link to the site or source clipping of the site.  Currently only showing the testcase itself.

Answer (score 0):

As per the **`snapshot`** (without any visibility to your script) you have shared to `select` from the `DropDown` you have to use the following **`Algorithm`** :

- Open one Website
- Click one button and then open go to another website
- Switch to the **`Frame`** with proper **`WebDriverWait`**
- Use **`Select`** Class to identify the `DropDown` element.
- Induce **`WebDriverWait`** for your target option to render in the **`HTML DOM`**
- Click on the intended **`option`**

Comment: Thank you  i think your algorithm is right. But i do not know what is proper WebdriverWait in selenium IDE

Comment: As you are working with `selenium-ide` you can use **`Thread.sleep()`** for the debug purpose. You can find a detailded discussion here [**`Make a page wait for 15 minutes`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47900735/make-a-page-wait-for-15-minutes/47900881#47900881). If my `Answer` have catered to you `Question` please mark the `Answer` as **`Accepted`** by clicking on the tick mark beside my `Answer` which is just below the `VoteDown` arrow so the tick mark turns green.